# Openstack instance cannot reach lan

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, routing, openstack

Instances launched on openstack cannot connect to anything on the lan, yet they happily reach the internet (google, yahoo, etc.)

Openstack setup:

- Ubuntu 12.04 running Openstack Essex
- Multi-node
- 1 Controller
- 1 Compute running nova-network

Dual ethernet cards on the servers. eth0 is on the office lan, eth1 is on the private lan.

- Internal office lan: 10.0.0.0/16 (10.0.0.1 - 10.0.255.255)
- Openstack private lan: 10.2.0.0/16

Instances get floating ip in the following range: 10.0.253.0/24

An instance with a floating ip can be reached from the office lan.
An instance is unable to reach the office lan directly (ping 10.0.0.2 fails)

I assume it's a missing forwarding rule on the compute host.

compute routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         firewall001.hq. 0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.0.0.0        *               255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
10.2.0.0        *               255.255.255.224 U         0 0          0 br100
192.168.122.0   *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 virbr0
```

Instance routing table:

```
Routing tables
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags    Refs      Use  Netif Expire
default            10.2.0.4           UGS         2      184 vtnet0
10.2.0.0/27        link#1             U           3      162 vtnet0
plum.novalocal     link#1             UHS         0        0    lo0
localhost          link#2             UH          0        0    lo0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a routing issue.

The actual fix is unknown, but moving all the vm to a 192.168.0.0/16 got me going.